# Delete from linux file based on another file

Tags: linux, bash

I have `2` files in `Linux` like below

`file1`

```
test_1
test_3
test_5
test_6
```

`file2`

```
test_1,smoke_test
test_2,rain_test
test_3,sun_test
test_4,wind_test
```

I want to compare these two files and delete the tables in `file1` that are present in `file2` that is the first part before `comma(,)`

Output required:

`file3`

```
test_5
test_6
```

I have tried like below

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

`output achieved`

```
test_1
test_3
test_5
test_6
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: `comm` matches the entire line, why would you expect it to just compare the first field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
$ grep -v -Ff <(cut -d',' -f1 file2) file1 >file3
```

`-v` : negation - return the non matched entries
`-F` : Fixed Regex matching instead of classic regex
`-f` : read patterns from file2
`<(cut .... file2)` : Command substitution. Feeds `grep -f` with the results of the `cut` => 1st column of file2

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1; next} !a[$1]' file2 file1
test_5
test_6
```

How it works:

1. `-F,`

   This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator.
2. `FNR==NR{a[$1]=1; next}`

   When reading the first file, `FNR==NR`, we assign a value of 1 (true) to the associative array `a` under the key of the first field.  We then skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
3. `!a[$1]`

   If we are on the second file, we print the line if `a[$1]` is not true.  In other words, we print each line from the second file, `file1`, if the first field was *not* seen in the first file, `file2`.

Comment: As an alternative , you can use on the second file1 a test like `(!($1 in a))` . It has been noted that using the `!a[$1]` format, memory space is reserved for every record in the second file (file1) without reason - you just need to test if `$1` belongs in `a`